# Fault domain and update domain in Azure

Tags: azure

I would like to know some simple explanation to understand about Fault domain and update domain in Azure.

Most of the theory is little confusing to me. So the below picture is what that i understand if we make it as a cluster environment to update the Hypervisor?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRdPF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Group of VMs that share common hardware are said to be in the same `fault domain.`

During planned maintenance by Microsoft VMs are required to reboot to complete the update.Group of VMs and underlying Hardware that are rebooted at the same time are said to be in the same `update domain`.